# How to stop printing log4j FileNotFound Error on console?

Tags: java, log4j, executable-jar

I created a utility for moving some text data into a SQL database and have implemented logging(log4j) for debugging purposes. 
Once i created a jar of my utility and called it for execution, the utility works fine but each time, the output is preceded by the below error message:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:306)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:324)
        at spotfire.loadtest.Driver.main(Driver.java:28)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (spotfire.loadtest.Driver).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Please note that my utility works and the text is inserted into the database. The only issue I face is how to get rid of this error message. Is there any way to stop printing it altogether??

Comment: It seems that log4j is not correctly configured. Are you getting log4j statements printed in your log file? Is log4j.properties in classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Either your log4j.properties has to be in classpath or you need to specify it as JVM Argument as

-Dlog4j.configuration={path to file}